# A good C alternative for Boost.Program_options?

Tags: c, parsing, command-line-arguments

Any good alternative written in C to replace Boost.Program_options? Given it's able to parse:

1. Short options like -h
2. Long options like --help --input-file
3. Parse repeated keys/options
4. Accepts key-value pairs: --mysql=/usr/lib
5. Parsing environmental variables and XML/INI files is optional.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are okay with the GPL license, you want [GNU getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/libc/Getopt.html).

Answer (score 4):

POSIX has [`getopt`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getopt.html), glibc adds [`getopt_long`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getopt.3.html).  Both the links I posted have examples.  None of them parses environment variables of XML/INI files, but those two don't really belong with command-line options parsing.  A quick google search results in libraries to be able to do those things though.

Answer (score 4):

GLib comes with a [commandline option parser](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Commandline-option-parser.html) that supports your first four requirements, and also a [key-value file parser](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Key-value-file-parser.html) that supports the fifth.